# std::optional from variable-length args and from std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, option-type, initializer-list, c++17

There is a specialization for `make_optional` from `std::initializer_list` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional):

```
template< class T, class... Args > 
constexpr std::optional<T> make_optional( Args&&... args );

template< class T, class U, class... Args > 
constexpr std::optional<T> make_optional( std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args );
```

The same is, for example, for `std::optional::emplace()`.

Why is there additional specialization fro `std::initializer_list`?